# What does と創る mean? (市民と創る教育改革)

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I found these

> 市民と創る教育改革

> ハハ... クイーンさまと創る理想の世界での姿にしてました。

- Does this と indicate something done with x?

I understood the sentences as

> An Educational reform made together with the citizens

> I made it look like the appearance I would have in the world me and the queen will make

Comment: I think your understanding is perfectly correct. Is it 創る that you not sure about? (と is _with_).

Comment: Side point, but isn't the speaker creating (the form of) _an_ _ideal_ _world_ with Queen-sama?